# How do i switch between planners at runtime

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, nav-core, local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to be able to switch between two planners based at runtime based on some logic devised.

How exactly do i do this if both are ros nodes?
(Is it possible to do this even if these nodes are not registered as planners)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277412/how-do-i-switch-between-planners-at-runtime/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are talking about `move_base` `local_planners`, you cannot switch between runtime out-of-the-box.

What you could do is to [write a "Default plugin"](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) which allows you to take in Topics/Services/Actions from a stand-alone node, and handle switching via a state machine or something.

Also, there are two new approaches that extend `move_base` and could help you with this, that might be worth investigating (however, I cannto guarantee for anything ;-) ):

- `move_base_flex` by magazino [link](https://github.com/magazino/move_base_flex)
- `nav_core2` by locusrobotics [link](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1